# Upload files not working in th new Google Developers Console Storage Browser

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've been using Google Cloud Storage successfully during the last few months with the old console but I'm now redirected to the new Google Developers Console and I have troubles uploading files.

In the new Google Developers Console, if I click on Storage / Cloud Storage / Storage Browser / MyBucket, I can still upload files a usual. But if I click in a sub-folder then nothing happens after I've selected the files I want to upload. And if I return to the root of my bucket I still can't upload, I need to select "Storage Browser" again to be able to upload files to the root (and only the root) of my bukcet...

Is this a known bug ? Is there another way to upload files with the new developers console ?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Hi Gérôme, this is a known bug and we will be rolling out a fix shortly. We're sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as jterrace said, this is a known bug.
You can work around it by doing one of the following:

1. drag/drop the files you wish to upload onto the browser, or
2. refresh the browser at the current location before uploading.

Both of these methods will work in the root and in directories.
Again, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi, Thanksfor your reply. I've tried both methods and only the first seems to work, but at least I've discovered the drag/drop method :) On a side note, because I was quite in a hurry to upload files, I also tried appengine-gcs-client in a quick and dirty servlet and it wasn't really hard to use :)